# What does Python socket error no 52 (Invalid Exchange) refer to?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up a Bluetooth link between a Raspberry Pi and an Arduino (Megapi). These are both mounted on a robot for a wireless robotics project. While running the Bluetooth server/listener on the Pi, I get the Invalid Exchange socket error. The troublesome code is shown below-

```
    self.host = "00:0D:19:EA:28:52"
    self.port = 3
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
    self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
```

The fourth line is where the error pops up-

```
File "Client.py", line 21, in __init__
  self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
  return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 52] Invalid exchange
```

Unfortunately, there appears to be very little documentation on socket errors available on the internet, other than one/two word descriptions of what the error codes mean. I was hoping you can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.10/net/bluetooth/lib.c#L68 translates Bluetooth errors into C errnos. EBADE (errno 52) is mapped to Bluetooth error code 0x06, defined as "Key Missing".

Comment: What does "Key Missing" tell me about the problem? I can't seem to find where the bug actually is!

Comment: Could be a pairing problem.